# Using ethtool from a linux user application to change network settings

Tags: linux, networking, real-time, ethercat

I'm developing an EtherCAT Master application on Xubuntu with the RT_PREEMPT patch so I can have real-time performance with EtherCAT communications.

I've found that some NIC's have the *rx-usecs* 'Coalesce parameter' set to a non-0 value by default.  Any non-0 setting will cause the network card to wait that many microseconds before generating an interrupt after receiving a network packet; however the network driver will then get pre-empted by my Real-Time applications, and cause significant delays in my application receiving EtherCAT IO from the network.

```
ecat@EcatLab:~/SIL/RealTimePlatform/EcMaster$ ethtool -c eth1
Coalesce parameters for eth1:
Adaptive RX: off  TX: off
stats-block-usecs: 0
sample-interval: 0
pkt-rate-low: 0
pkt-rate-high: 0

rx-usecs: 3
rx-frames: 0
rx-usecs-irq: 0
rx-frames-irq: 0

tx-usecs: 0
tx-frames: 0
tx-usecs-irq: 0
tx-frames-irq: 0

rx-usecs-low: 0
rx-frame-low: 0
tx-usecs-low: 0
tx-frame-low: 0

rx-usecs-high: 0
rx-frame-high: 0
tx-usecs-high: 0
tx-frame-high: 0
```

Currently I have to manually run ethtool with sudo for every network card I want to use for EtherCAT. This can be scripted, but ideally it should only be performed on the NIC actually configured for EtherCAT use, which is difficult to do outside the application.

Is there a way to call ethtool from within my linux application to configure the network settings for the NIC it is using? Or an API to perform the same?

My application runs as a non-root user with setcap to assign the CAP_NET_ADMIN and CAP_NET_RAW capabilities for EtherCAT use. Is this sufficient for calling ethtool as a subprocess, or are there additional permissions I require? Or can I even call ethtool to change coalesce settings without being root?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the part about capabilities, but you can call a CLI program from a program using `system()`.

Comment: Note that only values of 100 or above in `rx-usecs` denote microseconds. Lower non-zero values select some adaptive algorithm, in particular 3 is called "dynamic with reduced latency". networking/e1000e.txt in the Kernel docs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's too late to post my answer, but I'll give it a try anyway. I'm guessing the reason why the network driver is preempted is because the driver's IRQ handler is as a thread and its priority is lower than your RT app. Usually, IRQ handlers are threads in a kernel with a RT preempt patch. You can check this by running `ps -aux | grep <NIC NAME>` or something. In order not to allow preemption by the RT app, you can just give NIC handler a higher priority by running `sudo chrt --fifo -p <PRIORITY> <PID OF NIC HANDLER>`.